# Java regex - exclude newline from word boundary

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

I'm trying to come up with a Java regex which matches a word even when there is a `\n` in the input text. Kindly note that \n is supposed to appear as raw string. I am using the typical word boundary `\bHelloWorld\b` - https://regex101.com/r/Se5iVW/1 .

For example,

```
HelloWorld is a beautiful word \nHelloWorld\nHelloWorld\nHelloWorld hello noHelloWorld \n HelloWorldno noHelloWorld  HelloWorldno \nnoHelloWorld \nHelloWorld ...
```

In this, I expect 5 matches (first four `HelloWorld` and last one).

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with a positive lookbehind that matches `\b` or literal `\n` in alternations:

```bash
(?<=\\n|\b)HelloWorld\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q2N3wH/1)

Comment: Thanks. If I am using in a string - Pattern.compile("...") . How would the regex look like? 
Will this be correct - Pattern.compile("(?<=\\\\n|\\b)HelloWorld\\b");

Please let me know.

Comment: That will be `String regex = "(?<=\\\\n|\\b)HelloWorld\\b";`. You can click on `Code Generator` on regex101 link to get generated Java code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know about the code generator feature on regex101.

Comment: Also, can you kindly provide a explanation of the regex you came up with. As to how to interpret/read it while matching the input.

Comment: @pikaraider: I have added a brief explanation in answer already. Please let me know if this worked out for you and what additional query you have.